# Host reboot while docker running

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ros

I have a ROS system on my Ubuntu OS, which runs in Docker. I have rebooted the system while the docker was still running. 
After which ROS stopped working.
Whether the abrupt reboot would be a cause for this issue ?

Update:
1. No ros related commands were showing any output (It was just a blank line)
2. I have installed ROS separately on the host OS and tried roscore, it worked fine. I was able to see output for rostopic list.
3. I have re-installed OS, but issue persists inside docker.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Unless you've started container with `--privileged` or some privileges, docker container cannot reboot your host. If something fatal happens with container being launched unprivileged, container will stop, but not the host

Comment: @mulg0r Thanks for the response. However in my case after I reboot the host, the application which was running on the container has stopped working.

Comment: Of course, obviously if you start host, everything that is running in host is stopped. I thought you were saying that container had provoked host reboot, not you.

Comment: @mulg0r Thank you again. But after the host has come up, app which was running in the docker is not working as per the expectation. I am quite surprised whether reboot would cause this .. !!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. By the way, maybe it's useful for you start container with `--restart=always` or unless stopped mode

Comment: oh k.. I will check the given commands.. As of now I am reinstalling my Ubuntu...!!

Comment: Can you elaborate "ROS stopped working"? Does it output strange messages, is the problem perhaps that Docker is not running? Can you explain? Also "docker ps" and some similar information would be really beneficial. 
Also, I don't believe shutting down/resetting would create a memory corruption for Docker...

Comment: @maetulj  -  Unfortunately as of now I may not be able to provide the mentioned output as I have already reinstalled my OS.. FYI: ros related commands doesn't give any output, it just gives a blank line.. I will update here if the issue repeats again..

Comment: @maetulj I have updated the question with the latest update. Could you please check and let me know what could be the cause and the fix.?

Comment: @KK2491 how did you create the docker container? How did you install ROS, with a dockerfile or manually in the container?

Comment: RPS was installed from the Docker file.. I tried the same program in different system it worked perfectly fine.. I wonder what went wrong ..!!

Comment: @KK2491 I wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51118262/3702377), doesn't works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Quick Answer:

You can use `unless-stopped` or `always` option.

```
$ docker run --restart unless-stopped ros
```

> `unless-stopped` --> Restart the container unless it is explicitly stopped or Docker itself is stopped or restarted.
>
> `always`  --> Always restart the container if it stops.
>
> [Reference](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/)